# Conditional join in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I want to execute below query in Hive -

```
select * from supp a inner join trd_acct b
on
(a.btch_id = 11170 AND a.btch_id = b.btch_id)
OR (a.btch_id = 11164 AND a.supp_id = b.supp_id)
```

But getting error -

> FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10019]: Line 3:1 OR not supported in
>   JOIN currently 'supp_id'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can solve this with `UNION` :

```
select * from supp a inner join trd_acct b
 on a.btch_id = 11170 AND a.btch_id = b.btch_id
UNION ALL
select * from supp a inner join trd_acct b
 on a.btch_id = 11164 AND a.supp_id = b.supp_id
```

Or you can try `CASE EXPRESSION` :

```
select * from supp a
inner join trd_acct b
 on CASE WHEN a.btch_id = 11164 THEN a.supp_id 
         WHEN a.btch_id = 11170 THEN a.btch_id END
  = CASE WHEN a.btch_id = 11164 THEN b.supp_id
         WHEN a.btch_id = 11170 then b.btch_id END
```

Comment: @sagi..Query1 : I can do that using union in hive as hive not supported union all. But I want to do that not using union in Hive.
Query2: Hive not supported Case. 2nd query is not working in Hive

Comment: @Avijit I don't know HIVE syntax, does it support a replacement for `CASE` like `IF()` or something ? And what's wrong with the `UNION` solution

Comment: Hive version >= 1.2.0 supports both `UNION` and `UNION ALL`. Please refer - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Union

Answer (score 1):

Below query is working fine in Hive(Hadoop) -

```
select * from supp a inner join trd_acct b
where
(a.btch_id = 11170 AND a.btch_id = b.btch_id)
OR (a.btch_id = 11164 AND a.supp_id = b.supp_id)
```

I have tested in Hive Console.